# VBA: Schematic copy routine

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, copy, copy-paste

I had to solve an Excel problem with VBA today but i feel like a noob. My requirements are really simple But somehow I'm on the line.

I would like to add to each existing line, some variants on an additional sheet.

[Check out the scheme here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89MeN.jpg)

How is that possible? Can anyone help me pls?

Thanks for Feedback and your help.

Greetings
eXocode

The Solution was:

`Sub CopyData()

```
RowInSheet3 = 1

For RowInSheet1 = 1 To Sheets(1).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Sheets(3).Cells(RowInSheet3, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(RowInSheet1, 1)
    RowInSheet3 = RowInSheet3 + 1


    For RowInSheet2 = 1 To Sheets(2).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        Sheets(3).Cells(RowInSheet3, 1) = Sheets(2).Cells(RowInSheet2, 1)
        Sheets(3).Cells(RowInSheet3, 2) = Sheets(2).Cells(RowInSheet2, 2)
        RowInSheet3 = RowInSheet3 + 1
    Next

Next
```

End Sub`

Comment: copy Var sheet data into an array. ..... loop through cells in Entry sheet  .... for each iteration of the loop, copy one cell from Entry sheet followed by the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it; you will have to adjust the Ranges to your needs, but the basic algorithm should be what you are looking for:

```
Sub CopyData()

    RowInSheet3 = 1

    For RowInSheet1 = 1 To Sheets(1).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        Sheets(3).Cells(RowInSheet3, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(RowInSheet1, 1)
        RowInSheet3 = RowInSheet3 + 1


        For RowInSheet2 = 1 To Sheets(2).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
            Sheets(3).Cells(RowInSheet3, 1) = Sheets(2).Cells(RowInSheet2, 1)
            Sheets(3).Cells(RowInSheet3, 2) = Sheets(2).Cells(RowInSheet2, 2)
            RowInSheet3 = RowInSheet3 + 1
        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks amazing. Thx JensS

If I d'not know how many entries i wanna have in my "Entry-Sheet", i can probably not use the .Range("A1:A10") limiter...

How can i avoid this...? Simply with ("A:A") ?

Comment: I have added support for finding the last cell in sheet1 and sheet2 automatically.

Comment: Hey JensS now i got some time to try out your script and it works! Thx you so much.. <3 I got the first entry from sheet 1 with all variables from sheet 2 in my result sheet. Perfect, this is exactly what i expected. But the script does not continue automatically for Entry2, Entry 3 and so on.. How can i put  your logic in a loop which repeat this function for all variable entries on sheet 1?

Comment: The first for loop should find all entries in sheet1 (=should loop to the last cell with values in it); if it doesn't (depending on the Excel-version there might be differences that I am not aware of), maybe switch back to the "brute force" method and just loop to 1000 (or use a different algorithm to find the last cell with values in them). Let me know if that works...

Comment: Hello JensS, Thx you so much for your help and patience. I appreciate that..The Brutforce methode visualized a problem in the second loop. The routine copies never ending variables and can not return in to the first loop after completing the data from the second sheet.  

Video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3iYTsuFtkejZ3NMMVhBandUUkk/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Can you check what the value of Sheets(2).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row is? And also  if RowInSheet2 is counted up for each iteration?

Comment: Stackoverflow asked me to avoid long conversations in comments, but I can not start any chat due to low reputation. ^^The MsgBox showed an result of 153 rows sheet 2. But I could not understand how he counted these. I only noticed that Excel exactly interrupts after 153 row when I scrolled down in the document and then scale bar is getting smaller after this point. But it seems that he could not found the last row with data filed in. So I replaced the second sheet with an empty one and know it works as perfect. It seems there was an blank character in my second sheet. Thanks again for help!

Comment: Excellent. Could you then please accept my answer to close the topic.